# How to convert numpy to float32?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have a  `data` I want to split and convert it to  `float32` but it is showing the real number as a string

```
   data = open('Path dataset')
        for line in data:
        train = np.array([np.float32(x) for x in line.split(",")[:]])
```

And the error that showing me is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-53e8671c416d> in <module>
      1 for line in data_coba:
----> 2     train = np.array([np.float32(x) for x in line.split(",")[:]])          
      3 #print(train_test_coba)

<ipython-input-83-53e8671c416d> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 for line in data_coba:
----> 2     train = np.array([np.float32(x) for x in line.split(",")[:]])           
      3 #print(train_test_coba)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ï»¿50.89482266'
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: it cannot parse this `ï»¿` to convert to float

Comment: @abhilb yes correct but my data is real numbers it does not contain any of string ```ï»¿```

Comment: may be use regex to remove all unwanted characters

Comment: change the encoding while opening the file to `utf-8-sig` , ie. `open('Path dataset', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: You are hit by BOM. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: If the line did not contain these extra characters, `train = np.array(line.split(','), dtype=float)` should have been enough.  No need for the string by string conversion.  But all float conversions reject extra characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your dataset contains characters other than just comma-separated numbers. So the error is possibly occurring when it is trying to convert these non-numeric characters to float32. I suggest you check your dataset again and maybe try splitting it more.

Comment: Maybe you can separately check what `for x in line.split(",")[:]]` gives as output and move further from there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use encoding='utf-8' in the open function

```
data = open('Path dataset',encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: when I use this condition, I get this error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\ufeff51.45440668'`

Comment: What does the 'ï»¿' signify in the value? If it is ok to ignore those unwanted characters, you can replace these characters.

`In: np.float32(re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]', '', 'ï»¿50.89482266'))
Out: 50.89482`